# Golang, import pkg after go install

Tags: go, import

I am very new to go, I come from python. In order to learn I am recreating python builtin functions. 
I got stuck at my first function - range, it is not a generator yet.
I want to be able to:

```
// testmain.go

package main

import (
    "pyfuncs"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println( pyfuncs.range(12) )
    fmt.Println( pyfuncs.range(-12, -2, 3) )
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
[-12 -9 -6 -3]
*/
```

My `$GOPATH/` is structured in this way:

```
/$GOPATH/
        |
        | src/
        |    | imports/
        |    |        | pyfuncs/
        |    |        |        | pyrange.go (package pyfuncs)
        |    | learn/
        |    |      | testmain.go (package main) <- This doesnt work
        |    |      | ArraysAndSlices/...
        |    |      | Printf/...
        |
        | pkg/
        |    | linux_amd64/
        |    |            | imports/
        |    |            |        | pyfuncs.a
        | bin/...
```

I am in the testmain.go
How to access the functions from pyfuncs directory? 
I want to be able to access them from every future project like the fmt. In python I would just shove them in the `lib/` directory in python folder.

These are the errors:

```
cannot refer to unexported name pyfuncs.pyRange
undefined: pyfuncs.pyRange
```

Comment: Read [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).  The document describes how work with modules, packages and the go command.

Comment: In Golang a Function is Exported/Public if and only if it's first letter is capitalized. As such you can not access the function "pyRange", you will need to rename it to "PyRange".

Answer (score 0):

Functions to be imported have to start with capital letter.

Step by step:

1. `cd imports/pyfuncs`
2. `go install`
3. When trying to access pyfuncs do `imoprt "imports/pyfuncs"`
4. Access the function by `pyfuncs.PyRange`